# In Azure Devops, how to build a query to return a task If the state of another task under the same user story has changet

Tags: azure-devops

I have a user story with 3 (A, B, C) tasks and I am trying to build a query to return this user story if task A is done and task B is not yet active and same for C (if A and B are closed and C not yet active)

Type of query: work items and direct links with filter options: only return items that have matching links. Type of links: return selected link types: child

Comment: Please elaborate a bit of your expectation, it returns task in the title, but ask user story in the description. Also, are the child task ID known? Are you monitoring the child state (if A and B are closed and C not yet active) only, or when the state changed(could be other sate)?

Answer (score 0):

Work Item Queries do not support such complex tasks...

But (as a workaround) try you can use Excel integration: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/boards/backlogs/office/bulk-add-modify-work-items-excel?view=azure-devops&tabs=agile-process

1. Create a query to get stories and child tasks.
2. Link it to an excel book.
3. Create custom formulas to highlight stories by some color with started and not completed tasks. (but this option is more MS Office guru)))

Or you can try to use custom PowerBI reports: [Work items with direct links sample reports](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/report/powerbi/sample-boards-directlinks?view=azure-devops&tabs=powerbi)